# Powershell multiple IF and Elseif conditions

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

My script below works when I separate the IF/ELSE into two scripts (where the start-sleep occurs), but does not work when I run all of it in 1 script, what am I doing wrong?

```
$site = "XXX"
$1= $(try {something} catch {$null})


if ($1-eq $null) {do something
} 
elseif ($1-ne $null) {do something else
}

Start-Sleep 10

if ($1-eq $null) {do something
}
elseif ($1-ne $null) {do something else
}
```

The problem is the second IF always throws an error.

Comment: $testsite is still null because you never change it after it's original assignment of null

Comment: That helped, thank you.